# Абстрактный класс и его наследники

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, наследование, stl

Знаю, что если есть абстрактный клас(например: Account) и наследники абстрактного класа(PrivelegeAccount, SavingAccount), то можно через указатель на родительский класс(Account*) использовать наших наследников.

Так вот задача:
У нас должен быть динамический массив аккаунтов разных типов. Как такое сделать и можно ли через vector такое сотворить?

С уважением.

Comment: Так и объявляйте вектор с типом Account*, и можно будет в него помещать объекты наследники, но использовать вы сможете лишь те методы что доступны в родителе (здесь не рассматриваю явное приведение к классу предка). Подобные примеры есть в любом учебнике по ООП, можете посмотреть.

Comment: не, так не работает, пробовал

Comment: храните указатели(простые или умные)

Comment: @Evgenii Izhboldin,  если даже очень захотите, всеравно не сможете реализовать вектор с типом Account,  так как речь идет о том, что это абстрактный класс

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, ну я имел ввиду указатели

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам следует хранить элементы в векторе по указателю. Лучше использовать smart pointer. Что то вроде:

```
struct Account
{ 
    virtual ~Account() = default; // Пожалуй все-таки не стоит забывать про виртуальный деструктор
    virtual std::string GetMessage() = 0;
};

struct PrivelegeAccount final: public Account
{
    virtual std::string GetMessage() override final { return "PrivelegeAccount"; }
};

typedef std::unique_ptr<Account> AccountPtr;

int main()
{
    std::vector<AccountPtr> vector;
    vector.emplace_back(std::make_unique<PrivelegeAccount>());

    for (const auto& account : vector)
        std::cout << account->GetMessage() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Во первых тут базовая структура  не  является абстрактным классом( суть не в этом), во вторых  контейнеры лучше заполнять  обьектами  shared_ptr

Comment: Контейнеры можно и нужно часто заполнять unique_ptr. Абстрактным класс может быть "логически". А вот виртуальный деструктор не помешал бы.

Comment: А почему обязательно unique_ptr или почему лучше shared_ptr ?

Comment: @Dim Не обязательно unique_ptr. Все зависит от задачи. В данном примере вид указателя значения не имеет.

Comment: @Dim shraed_ptr - указатель с разделяемым владением. unique_ptr же единолично владеет объектом. И, если вам не требуется наличия указателя на один объект в нескольких местах вашей программы, логичнее использовать unque_ptr, который, как минимум, "легче" чем shared_ptr

Comment: @KoVadim, тогда поясните пожалуйста непроффессионалу: если я захочу использовать этот контейнер в функции и возвращать какой то элемент  контейнера (примитивный пример конечно), то как тогда быть?

Comment: А что такое возвращать? Сделать копию? (никто не мешает обычно) или "изъять"? Но в любом случае всегда можно придумать ещё сотню случаев, когда конкретно Вам не подойдет unique_ptr или даже shared_ptr. В общем случае - если вектор монопольно владеет - unuque_ptr, если нет, shared_ptr. Если сложнее - делается обертка вокруг вектора (агрегирующая).